# Setting color of the defaultMarker by using more than "hue"

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to set marker color to the following color:

Hue (H): 0º
Saturation (S): 100%
Value (V): 80%

But the default marker can only be colored using the "hue".

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latlng)
                    .title("Marker")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(myColor)));
```

`myColor` is supposed to be a `float` describing the "hue" of color. However, in order to set it to the exact color I want, I also need to set the **saturation** and the **value**. Is it not allowed to set them somehow? Are the decimal places for the saturation/value? How am I supposed to set it? Is creating my own marker-PNGs the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is creating my own marker-PNGs the only solution?

Yes. And it's the best solution too. Default markers may appear different on different devices depending on what drawables are bundled into Google Play Services. Avoid them when possible.

Also you may want to make a request for `BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue, saturation, value)` on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) if you feel that is important.

Comment: @ercan And I have starred the issue. But don't expect it to come out very soon ;)

Comment: Still no change, extremely annoying to convert between 2 color spaces and still not getting it right. Can not comprehend why using HSL here instead of plain RGB.